# Python multiprocessing Manager process not exiting after successfully stopping parent processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, keyboardinterrupt

I'm wrote the following demo script to replicate the multiprocessing handling logic from a more complex case (from now on the original code), however the key parts should be there.

The original code running with python 3.10.12 had a memory leak when sometimes stopped by CTRL+C, as seen with `htop` in Linux where stale processes were hogging up RAM. After spending some time trying to fix it, I aimed at getting all processes terminated and check their exit codes. After getting exit code -15 (correct for CTRL+C) for all processes in the printout after hitting CTRL+C, I thought the leak would stop but it persists.

The demo script code is the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


class ProcessManager:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.proc_map = {}

        self.map_procs()

    def map_procs(self):
        for i in range(1):
            self.proc_map[i] = mp.Process(target=self.parent_loop)
        print("mapped processes in orchestrator")

    def start_procs(self):
        # Start all processes
        for i, proc in self.proc_map.items():
            proc.start()
            print(f"Parent process {i} started.")

        # wait for processes to finish
        for _, proc in self.proc_map.items():
            try:
                proc.join()  # wait for the process to finish (it may or may not, depending on loops)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                for _, proc in self.proc_map.items():
                    print(f"Terminating process {proc}...")
                    proc.terminate()
                for _, proc in self.proc_map.items():
                    proc.join()  # wait for termination to finish

    def parent_loop(self):
        p = Parent()
        p.parent_loop()


class Parent:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.queue = mp.Manager().Queue()

        self.child = ChildDaemon(self.queue)
        self.dummy_file_in_memory = self.load_big_file()

        self.slow_init_func(5)

        self.child.daemon_proc.start()

    def slow_init_func(self, t):
        print("slow init func")
        time.sleep(t)

    def load_big_file(self):
        file_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 20
        dummy_data = bytearray(file_size)
        return dummy_data

    def parent_loop(self):
        while True:
            print(f"parent loop: queue counter {self.queue.get()}")
            time.sleep(5)


class ChildDaemon:
    def __init__(self, queue) -> None:
        self.queue = queue
        self.daemon_proc = mp.Process(target=self.child_loop, args=(queue,))
        self.daemon_proc.daemon = True

    def child_loop(self, queue):
        counter = 0
        while True:
            print("child loop")
            time.sleep(1)
            try:
                queue.get_nowait()
            except:
                pass
            try:
                queue.put(counter, block=False)
            except:
                pass
            counter += 1


if __name__=="__main__":
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')

    orch = ProcessManager()
    orch.start_procs()

    for key, proc in orch.proc_map.items():
        print("Checking exitcodes of supervisor processes...")
        print(f"{key} ({proc}) exitcode: {proc.exitcode}")
```

On Mac OS 14.1.2 and python 3.9.12, when I CTRL+C out of it, I get:

```
mapped processes in orchestrator
Parent process 0 started.
slow init func
child loop
child loop
parent loop: queue counter 0
child loop
child loop
child loop
child loop
parent loop: queue counter 4
child loop
child loop
^CTerminating process <Process name='Process-1' pid=13652 parent=13650 started>...
Process Process-1:2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/******/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/******/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/******/Projects/processes_leak/src.py", line 74, in child_loop
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
Checking exitcodes of supervisor processes...
0 (<Process name='Process-1' pid=13652 parent=13650 stopped exitcode=-SIGTERM>) exitcode: -15
```

`htop` is showing this after the script ends:
[image]

**Notes**

- My hope here is that the solution for this will translate to the original code as well.
- In the original code, I cannot use an executor, as I'm encountering some non-picklable objects and I want to handle the process management in a similar way to the demo.

**Edit**

Thanks to the comment by @relent95, I believe the issue lies in the mp.Manager() call. I can observe python processes after even the narrower script below has finished.

The question becomes how to correctly handle closing the manager process (**ideally without using a context manager**, as the original project is more complex. More specifically, is that is needed, since the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers) seem to say that *Manager processes will be shutdown as soon as they are garbage collected or their parent process exits*?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


class ProcessManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.organise()

    def organise(self):
        p = mp.Process(target=self.start_manager)
        p.start()
        try:
            p.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('pm exception')
            try:
                self.m.shutdown()
            except:
                pass
            p.terminate()
            p.join()

    def start_manager(self):
        self.m = mp.Manager()
        self.q = self.m.Queue()
        try:
            time.sleep(10)
        finally:
            print('start_manager exception')
            self.m.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pm = ProcessManager()
```

Comment: It's unclear. See [ask]. What are you asking? Are you saying the memory is not returned to the OS when the processes exited? Then what is the procedure to reproduce it? And what is the procedure to examine it happened? I am CERTAIN you are misinterpreting the result of your experiment. Also, your code will behave unexpectedly because you are terminating child processes manually and you missed  the server process created by the ```multiprocessing.Manager()```.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am referring to the processes showing up in htop after the script has finished as a memory leak, as every time I complete a script run, new stale ones pop-up. With my current knowledge, I understand this should not be happening as the process is killed and is "stopped" with exit code -15. I was not at all considering the Manager object, so I will look into it.

Comment: In short, the issue is htop rows referring to the script after the script's main process has finished, yes I'm saying I believe the memory is not returned, running the script reproduces the behavior, killing all related processes, re-running the script and checking with htop is how I examine it. As for terminating processes this way, I'm looking into other ways but running into other issues.

Comment: You missed the server process created by the ```multiprocessing.Manager()```. If you don't need a manager server, just do like ```mp.Queue()```, instead of ```mp.Manager().Queue()```.

Comment: Also don't say it's a memory leak. It is just that child processes didn't exit. It was caused because you terminated the parent process of them, so the automatic cleanup routine of the multiprocessing library didn't run.

Comment: Yes, I had a reason to go to mp.Manager.Queue(), various memory leak / speed bug in Linux for our use case that Manager().Queue() solved. (I took questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085458/why-is-multiprocessing-queue-get-so-slow), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439194/python-multiprocessing-queue-vs-multiprocessing-manager-queue/45236748#45236748) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439194/python-multiprocessing-queue-vs-multiprocessing-manager-queue/45236748#45236748) as reference). So I'm trying to see what's left to close the Manager.

Comment: The non-cleanup of such processes in the original code leads to considerable chunks of memory being reserved indefinitely after the main python process has ended. I will edit the title to avoid any possible confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to not leave orphan processes when handling an exception alongside a Manager() child process.

The key seems to be not to call Process.terminate(). Regardless of whether Manager.shutdown() was called beforehand, calling terminate() seems to not do the cleanup I would expect and leaves orphan processes behind, as can be observed by running (and interrupting with CTRL+C) my initial post's update section code.

This is clearly mentioned under `terminate()` in the [3.12.1 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/multiprocessing.html) (but not in the same place in 3.9 docs):

> terminate()
> Terminate the process. On POSIX this is done using the SIGTERM signal; on Windows TerminateProcess() is used. Note that exit handlers and finally clauses, etc., will not be executed.
>
> Note that descendant processes of the process will not be terminated – they will simply become orphaned.

This code below does not leave an orphan on Mac OS 14.1.2 and python 3.9.12:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


class ProcessManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.organise()

    def organise(self):
        p = mp.Process(target=self.start_manager)
        p.start()
        try:
            p.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('pm exception')
            pass
        finally:
            # p.terminate() # calling this before p.join() leaves orphans
            p.join()
            # p.close() # this is irrelevant to orphans

    def start_manager(self):
        self.m = mp.Manager()
        self.q = self.m.Queue()
        try:
            time.sleep(5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        finally:
            print('start manager exception')
            # calling Manager.shutdown() is irrelevant
            # the Manager process exits when the parent process exits
            self.m.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pm = ProcessManager()
```