# Adding a shared object to a manager.Namespace

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

[This seems to be a `python 3.6` bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue30256)

When assigning a `manager.Queue` to a `manager.Namespace` attribute one gets an `TypeError`. To reproduce it is simple:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Manager
>>> manager = Manager()
>>> np = manager.Namespace()
>>> np.shared_queue = manager.Queue()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\users\leonardo.schettini\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 1065, in __setattr__
    return callmethod('__setattr__', (key, value))
File "c:\users\leonardo.schettini\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 772, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\leonardo.schettini\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 228, in serve_client
    request = recv()
File "c:\users\leonardo.schettini\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
File "c:\users\leonardo.schettini\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 881, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
TypeError: AutoProxy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'manager_owned'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439194/python-multiprocessing-queue-vs-multiprocessing-manager-queue), I found that `manager.Queue` is just

> an address (proxy) pointing to shared queue managed by the multiprocessing.Manager() object

If one tries to assign a `multiprocessing.Queue` instead a `RuntimeError` is raised. This makes sense if you consider that the `multiprocessing.Queue` can't be pickled (information on provided link)

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error on Ubuntu.  So either this is an installation error on your particular computer, or this is a Windows related error.

Comment: Probably Ruindows error then. I also found [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue30256)

Comment: It could be a 3.6 bug, then.  My test was with 3.5 (and it also works on 2.7). I do not have 3.6 anywhere for testing.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I installed 3.6.5 on a virtual machine (ubuntu), and the error appears. So this is a 3.6 bug or feature.