# How to use Queue correctly with ProcessPoolExecutor in Python?

Tags: python, queue, process-pool

I am trying to use a queue to load up a bunch of tasks and then have a process pool setup go at it where each process pops-out a task out of the queue and works on it.  I am running into problems in that the setup is not working.  Something is blocking the processes from getting started and I need help in figuring out the bug.  E.g. the queue is filled up correctly, however, when the individual process runs, it doesn't start processing the task subroutine.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Aug 30 17:08:42 2022

@author: Rahul
"""

import threading
import queue
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


q = queue.Queue()

# some worker task


def worker(id, q):

    print(f'{id}:: Worker running', flush=True)
    while q.unfinished_tasks > 0:
        item = q.get()
        print(f'{id}::Working on {item}', flush=True)
        print(f'{id}::Finished {item}', flush=True)
        q.task_done()

        print(f'{id}::Sleeping. Item: {item}', flush=True)

        time.sleep(0.1)
    print(
        f'We reached the end.  Queue size is {q.unfinished_tasks}', flush=True)


def main():

    print('running main')
    # Send thirty task requests to the worker.
    for item in range(30):
        q.put(item)

    # Confirm that queue is filled
    print(f'Size of queue {q.unfinished_tasks}')
    id = 0

    # start process pool
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        executor.map(worker, [1, 2, 3, 4], [q, q, q, q])

    # Block until all tasks are done.
    q.join()
    print('All work completed')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This creates the following output and is stuck after that, no control of keyboard etc., have to shutdown IDE and restart.

```
running main
Size of queue 30
```

Answer (score 3):

For multiprocessing, there are 2 ways to uses a queue.

You have to either

1. use queue as shared global via `initializer` parameter or
2. use a manager

See [Python multiprocessing.Queue vs multiprocessing.manager().Queue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439194/python-multiprocessing-queue-vs-multiprocessing-manager-queue) for examples for how to set it up.

Below is an example of using a `manager` of OP's use case.

A few things to highlight:

1. Uses `manager.Queue()` which helps share the queue across different processes.
2. Typically for worker process, it's better to use `while True` loop that terminates when seeing some `SENTINEL` value. This will allow the worker to wait even if all current work is done, in case there are more work coming. It's also more robust than `q.empty()` check (or `q.unfinished_tasks`, which doesn't exist in multiprocessing version)
3. Using the `SENTINEL` approach requires adding 4 `SENTINEL` values, 1 for each process, after all the tasks.
4. `with ProcessPoolExecutor ...` context manager is blocking, meaning it will wait until all Processes exits before continuing to the next lines. You may consider using explicit shutdown for non-block statments, e.g.

```
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
executor.map(...)
executor.shutdown(wait=False)
```

Now finally, the example solution:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing as mp
import time



# some worker task
SENTINEL = 'DONE'

def worker(id, q):

    print(f'{id}:: Worker running', flush=True)
    # better to use the while True with SENTINEL
    # other methods such as checking 'q.empty()' may be unreliable.
    while True:  
        item = q.get()
        if item == SENTINEL:
            q.task_done()
            break
        print(f'{id}::Working on {item}', flush=True)
        print(f'{id}::Finished {item}', flush=True)
        q.task_done()

        print(f'{id}::Sleeping. Item: {item}', flush=True)

        time.sleep(0.1)
    print(
        f'We reached the end.', flush=True)


def main():

    print('running main')
    # Send thirty task requests to the worker.
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        q = manager.Queue()

        for item in range(30):
            q.put(item)

        # adding 4 sentinel values at the end, 1 for each process.
        for _ in range(4):
            q.put(SENTINEL)

        # Confirm that queue is filled
        print(f'Approx queue size: {q.qsize()}')
        id = 0

        # start process pool
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            executor.map(worker, [1, 2, 3, 4], [q, q, q, q])

        print('working')
        # Block until all tasks are done.
        q.join()
        print('All work completed')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: In worker() when SENTINEL item is reached, queue.task_done() is not being called.  Does that mean that SENTINEL persists in queue forever without getting popped out fully?

Comment: Could you also please pin-point why while True forever loop construct is needed in worker() beyond the completion of main() thread?  I saw the Python doc example with forever while loop, and the worker process keeps running in background long after main thread finished and control returned back to IDE prompt.  I confirmed it by adding an item to queue by typing q.put(some_item) on interpreter prompt, and it triggered the worker() automatically.  1/2

Comment: Contd. 2/2 I only want the worker to start monitoring queue when some event tells it that q is being used of about to be used.  Rest of the time, I would like the worker to either stay asleep or be finished, so a new instance can be created.  Otherwise, the worker keeps using cpu cycles in the background to continuously run the ‘while True’ loop and exiting out of it.

Comment: @BuddyLi you are correct, it does indeed need `q.task_done()` after reaching the `SENTINEL` also. The answer is updated. This would successfully terminate all worker nodes after the task is done. The reason not to use `q.empty()` check is because that may lead to race conditions. Suppose there is 1 item left, 2 processes both check `q.empty()` before either one calls `q.get()`. Then, both process will enter the loop and try to get the 1 item. 1 process will be left hanging (or until timeout). You may also want some error handling using `except queue.Empty` in that case. So, sentinel is cleaner

Comment: does q.get() create a block until q.task_done() is called?

Comment: no, `q.get()` creates a block until it gets the next item from the queue. `q.join()` creates a block until all `q.task_done()` is called for all the items in the queue.